# Grids in a figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, annotations, grid, line, figure

I'd like to add lines to an opened figure in MATLAB e.g. splitting the figure into 15 rows, without plotting it on an axes (I want whatever grid I input to be part of a non interactive background). How is this done?

Comment: there is a nice blog post by @Steve Eddins about displaying grids: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/02/17/pixel-grid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can manipulate the grid lines so as to give the appearance of dividing the image into 15x15 blocks, without having to plot each on a separate axes.

```
img=imread('peppers.png');
imagesc(img)
[nX,nY,~]=size(img);
nSeg=15;

set(gca,'xtick',linspace(0,nY,15+1),'xticklabel',[],...
    'xgrid','on','xcolor','w',...
    'ytick',linspace(0,nX,15+1),'ytickLabel',[],...
    'ygrid','on','ycolor','w',...
    'gridLineStyle','-','linewidth',1)
```

[image]

---

#### Blank figure:

To divide a blank figure,

```
nSeg=15;
set(gca,'xtick',linspace(0,1,15+1),'xticklabel',[],...
    'xgrid','on','xcolor','k',...
    'ytick',linspace(0,1,15+1),'ytickLabel',[],...
    'ygrid','on','ycolor','k',...
    'gridLineStyle','-','linewidth',1)
```

[image]

Comment: This can be done for figures [figure(.)] as well? I only want an empty figure to be divided in that way. I'm assuming the image processing commands would be unnecessary in that case.

Comment: Yes, it can be done for an empty figure. Just replace `nX` and `nY` with `1` and change `'w'` to `'k` and remove the `imagesc` command. You're all set now. See my edit for an example. Note that there is no "image processing" being done here.